# ¿Cuál es la manera correcta para redirigir paquetes en un servidor linux?

Tags: linux, servidor

Quiero lograr que un cliente envíe una imagen a un servidor en `Linux` para que éste lo almacene, y que posteriormente redirija la imagen a otros clientes. La duda que tengo es de qué manera puedo redirigir la imagen, pues lo único que se me ocurre es con una aplicación (por ejemplo en `java`) que reciba los paquetes y posteriormente lo reenvíe a otro cliente.

Comment: Si entiendo bien: quieres levantar una app que sea capaz de recibir un archivo subido desde un formulario (o bien mediante curl o como sea) y luego reenvíe ese archivo a N clientes. ¿Cómo quieres reenviarlo? ¿Un mail con un attachment? ¿Un mail con un link de descarga?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con rsync. En los linux a los que tiene que reenviar los ficheros tienes que configurar el servidor.
En el servidor que recibe el fichero inicialmente mete en el cron la ejecución el rsync cada cierto tiempo, las modificaciones las va a replicar en los demás.

Puedes también hacer un script que copie cada cierto tiempo el fichero via scp